# How to echo double quote into file without new line in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I want to write `"` sign using Batch in the file.

```
echo| set /p=""" >> abc.txt
```

This doesn't work as intended because it gives errors sending data to my file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea "three quotes" idea wasn't bad. But due to impaired quotes, the parser doesn't process it right. You have to escape one of them (one of the outer ones - escaping the middle one doesn't work):

```
<nul set /p =^""" >> abc.txt
```

or

```
<nul set /p =""^" >> abc.txt
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) describes in detail, how `cmd` does parsing.

Also I changed `echo| set /p...` with `<nul set /p`, which is much faster. Piping generates two new `cmd` processes, because each side of the pipe is run in a separate process, which costs time.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result for adding single, double-quote `"`:

```
echo| set /p=^""^">>abc.txt
```

Where this will give a result of double, double-quote `""`

```
echo| set /p=^"""^">>abc.txt
```

To break it down, we escape the opening and closing quotations `^"` with the desired result inbetween, these examples shows the desired results in parenthesis, with the escaped `"` outside of the parenthesis `^"(")^"` or `^"("")^"`

In short, no matter how many double quotes you want inbetween, as long as the opening and closing double-quotes are escaped.

So using the parenthesized examples as above, if you actually do:

```
echo echo| set /p=^"(")^"
```

it will only return the result of `(")`

**Note** the parsing is different when using `echo|` compared to @stephan's solution using `<nul` as pipe will initiate a second process and `<nul` does not.

Comment: The parsing is different. Your escaping doesn't work with my `<nul` method and my escaping doesn't work with the `echo|` method. But `<nul` is faster (that's why I used it instead of piping `echo`) , because piping creates an additional `cmd` process.